# AJAX doesn't always call the controller action, but always processes the success

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Alright, I am having a little bit of trouble that I have not seen before and it isn't actually reproducible.  I have a textbox that takes in a number and then a button that does an ajax call when pressed.  This calls an action in my controller that then updates the database with the value in the textbox.  The problem is that while debugging sometimes it works, other times it doesn't.  You can place a break point in the action in the controller and it isn't always hit, but even if the action isn't called the success call from the ajax is still executed.  Usually it works the first few times after the debugger is startedbut then it stops and it doesn't matter if you refresh the page.  I don't see any errors in Chrome or Visual Studios.  I also tried to see if I could find something in Intellitrace but had no luck.

**This is my action:**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UpdateIncremental(int QueryID, int? Incremental)
{
    Datamart_MedsDBContext DBContext = new Datamart_MedsDBContext();
    ss_Queries query = DBContext.ss_Queries.FirstOrDefault(m => m.QueryID == QueryID);
    query.IncrementalLookBack = Incremental;
    query.UpdatedBy = "CHMCCORP\\" + Session["UserName"].ToString();
    query.UpdatedOn = System.DateTime.Now;
    DBContext.ss_Queries.Attach(query);
    DBContext.Entry(query).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
    DBContext.SaveChanges();
    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**View:**

```
<input type="text" id="Incremental" value="@ViewBag.Incremental" />
<input id="editIncremental" type="button" name="editIncremental" value="Update" />
```

**Ajax:**

```
$("#editIncremental").on("click", function () {
    var reg = /(^$)|(^[0-9]*$)/;
    var incremental = $('#Incremental').val();
    var valid = reg.test(incremental);
    var queryID = "@Session["QueryID"]";
    if (!valid) {
        alert("The incremental load must be a number!");
    } else {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("UpdateIncremental", "Home")',
        data: {
                QueryID: queryID, Incremental: incremental
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
                if (data == true) {
                    alert('Incremental Lookback has been updated!')
                    //window.location.reload();
                }
                else {
                    alert('There is some error');
                }
            }

        });
    }
});
```

I know that this will be pain since it isn't repeatable and isn't guaranteed.  I am just looking for maybe a point into the right direction.

Comment: need to stringify your data when you set `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` otherwise jQuery will uriEncode it

Comment: No luck.  But other ajax calls work as they should and don't have this problem.

Comment: Sounds like your AJAX is getting cached. Try adding the `cache: false` option to your `$.ajax` call.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Well now, that actually worked.  At least it worked about 15 times straight I should say.  If you want to make that the answer I will gladly mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working in IE, turn off caching. Chrome doesn't seem to need it.

```
    $.ajax({
        cache:false,
```